# error inserting to sqlite database error code 19 constraint failed

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This error keeps showing every time I try to insert a new record in the database. I know the reason for this i think is the duplicate of the primary. I set the primary key to `AUTO INCREMENT`. How can I fix this error?

here's the

**SQLHandler.java**

```
public class SQLHandler {
    public static final String KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER = "roommoveholder";
    public static final String KEY_ROOM = "room";

    public static final String KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER = "itemmoveholder";
    public static final String KEY_ITEMNAME = "itemname";
    public static final String KEY_ITEMVALUE = "itemvalue";
    public static final String KEY_ROOMHOLDER = "roomholder";

    public static final String KEY_MOVENAME = "movename";
    public static final String KEY_ID1 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID2 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID3 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID4 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_MOVEDATE = "movedate";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymovingfriend";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_SORTANDPURGE = "sortandpurge";
    public static final String KEY_RESEARCH = "research";
    public static final String KEY_CREATEMOVINGBINDER = "createmovingbinder";
    public static final String KEY_ORDERSUPPLIES = "ordersupplies";
    public static final String KEY_USEITORLOSEIT = "useitorloseit";
    public static final String KEY_TAKEMEASUREMENTS = "takemeasurements";
    public static final String KEY_CHOOSEMOVER = "choosemover";
    public static final String KEY_BEGINPACKING = "beginpacking";
    public static final String KEY_LABEL = "label";
    public static final String KEY_SEPARATEVALUES = "separatevalues";
    public static final String KEY_DOACHANGEOFADDRESS = "doachangeofaddress";
    public static final String KEY_NOTIFYIMPORTANTPARTIES = "notifyimportantparties";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "movingname";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "movingrooms";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE3 = "movingitems";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE4 = "todolist";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_MOVEDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_MOVENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_2 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_3 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE3 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_ITEMNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ITEMVALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_ROOMHOLDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +   
            KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_4 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE4 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID4 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_SORTANDPURGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_RESEARCH + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CREATEMOVINGBINDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ORDERSUPPLIES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_USEITORLOSEIT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TAKEMEASUREMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_CHOOSEMOVER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_BEGINPACKING + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_LABEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_SEPARATEVALUES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_DOACHANGEOFADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_NOTIFYIMPORTANTPARTIES + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_2);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_3);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE3);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE4);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SQLHandler(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SQLHandler open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createMove(String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MOVENAME, smovename);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
    }

    public long addRooms(String sroommoveholder, String sroom){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER, sroommoveholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ROOM, sroom);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv);
    }

    public long addItems(String sitemmoveholder, String sroomholder, String sitemname, String sitemvalue){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER, sitemmoveholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMHOLDER, sroomholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, sitemname);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMVALUE, sitemvalue);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, cv);
    }

    public long todoList(String todoitem){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(todoitem, "Done");
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE4, null, cv);
    }

    public Cursor getMove(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

}
```

and

**ListMovingNames.java**

```
public class ListMovingNames extends Activity {
    ListView MoveList;
    SQLHandler SQLHandlerview;
    Cursor cursor;
    Button addMove;
    EditText etAddMove;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectorcreatemove);

        addMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddMove);
        etAddMove = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMoveName);

        MoveList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMoveItems);
        SQLHandlerview = new SQLHandler(this);

        SQLHandlerview = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
        SQLHandlerview.open();

        cursor = SQLHandlerview.getMove();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[]{SQLHandler.KEY_MOVENAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text};

        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        MoveList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        SQLHandlerview.close();

        addMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        String ssmoveName = etAddMove.getText().toString();
                        SQLHandler entry = new SQLHandler(ListMovingNames.this);
                        entry.open();
                        entry.createMove(ssmoveName);
                        entry.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Is there any method for this? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert an item into table 1 without setting "movedate" as well, which cannot be null...I think that's the constraint it's bugging you about...

EDIT:
Try this method and see if it works

```
public long createMove(String smovename){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MOVENAME, smovename);
    cv.put(KEY_MOVEDATE, "something");
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: whoa! your right! thank you so much man! so if I want to make KEY_MOVEDATE empty I should just remove the NOT NULL right?